# 0 eigenvalue for a symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, matrices

Let $T\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric tridiagonal matrix having the off--diagonal entries equal to -1.  The diagonal entries are all positive, $a_i>0$, $i=\overline{1,n}$, and there exist $j$ and $k$, $j\neq k$ such that $a_j=a_k\leq 1$. $a_j$ and $a_k$   are the smallest diagonal entries.

I'm interested under what supplemental conditions can such a matrix have the smallest eigenvalue equal to 0?

Comment: could you give some motivation/background?

Comment: The matrix $T$ is the linearization of a tridiagonal cooperative dynamical system around an equilibrium point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To simplify things a little, I describe conditions under which the smallest eigenvalue is strictly positive. These can be adjusted to get equality to zero.

**Necessary and sufficient** conditions for positive definiteness of the tridiagonal matrix in question are described below.

**Definition (Chain Sequence).**  A sequence $\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k > 0}$  is a chain sequence if there exists another sequence $\lbrace y_k \rbrace_{k\ge 0}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  x_k = y_k(1-y_{k-1}),
\end{equation*}
where $y_0 \in [0,1)$ and $y_k \in (0,1)$ for $k > 0$.

By the Wall-Wetzel Theorem, your tridiagonal matrix is positive definite **if and only if**

\begin{equation*}
  \left\lbrace \frac{1}{a_ka_{k+1}} \right\rbrace_{k=1}^{n-1}
\end{equation*}

is a chain sequence.

**Example.** In particular, if the entries of the matrix satisfy,

\begin{equation*}
  0 < \frac{1}{a_ka_{k+1}} < \frac{1}{4\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)},\quad  k=1,\ldots,n-1,
\end{equation*}
then it is positive definite.

---

For additional information and details about this material, please see:

1. M. Andelic, and C. M. Da Fonesca. *Sufficient conditions for positive definiteness of tridiagonal matrices revisited*. (2010).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this approach and the paper.

Comment: You are welcome; also note that the Example gives a sufficient (not necessary) condition, while the theorem cited is an IFF.

Comment: @Suvrit, Hi ! If we have tridiagonal positive semidefinite matrix with positive entries then is the sequence $\{\frac{b_{i}^{2}}{a_{i}a{i+1}}\}$ a chain sequence ? I know for positive definite matrix it is, but what about this case?